# Does Crichton's Daughter Have a Non-Zero Chance of Having Biological Children with Another Sebacean?

Tags: farscape

In the episode of Farscape, "[Look At The Princess - The Maltese Crichton](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Look_at_the_Princess_-_The_Maltese_Crichton)", John is seen interacting with the holographic representation of his future daughter (Katrana, according to the non-canon short-story [Horizons](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Horizons) by Farscape co-creator [Rockne S. O'Bannon](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Rockne_S._O%27Bannon)). Earlier in the plot arc ("[Look At The Princess - A Kiss Is But A Kiss](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Look_at_the_Princess_-_A_Kiss_is_but_a_Kiss)"), it is revealed that [Princess Katralla](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Katralla) has had her DNA poisoned. However, due to being a non-[Sebacean](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Sebacean), John is said to be compatible and therefore a viable option to continue the dynastic line.

My wondering is whether John's daughter, inheriting DNA from both her human father and her DNA-poisoned Sebacean mother, would have a non-zero chance of being able to have children with another Sebacean from her own planet (or elsewhere); or is it still the end of the dynastic line despite [Empress Novia](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Novia)'s efforts, merely delayed by one generation?

I'm thinking the answer might be yes (there's a non-zero chance that she could have children), but I don't really understand genetics well enough to be certain. I know that having an XX and XY pair can yield either XX or XY where X could come from either parent, and having a daughter would mean that an X came from Crichton, but I don't know whether that would negate the other poisoned X inherited from Katralla or if the poisoned DNA would still prevent compatibility between Crichton's daughter and other Sebaceans, or if such is even knowable without additional canonized input from the creators.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows (and I don't think it's addressed in the comics, where they make an appearance too). Plus it's magic space DNA poison - it can do whatever the writers want it to.

Comment: Have you watched the whole series? There's more information in later episodes, but I don't want to spoil the plot if you haven't watched it all

Comment: @HorusKol I don't recall any other information in the series about John and Katralla's child. It is heavily implied later on that sebaceans are basically humans with "modifications".

Comment: @user25730 it's not specific to John and Katralla's child... I don't want to say more due to spoilers if this is the OPs first time with the show

Comment: @HorusKol yes, but that's the one that's affected by the DNA poison.

Comment: @user25730: You raise a good point, and I do agree, that the poison can do whatever the writers desire, ultimately. I suppose answering this question might require a fuller understanding of the nature/specific effects of the poison (which are unrevealed to the audience, to my knowledge)?

Comment: @HorusKol: Thank you for being considerate about spoilers; I saw the full series a long time ago, but I'm going through the series again now. So, no worries about spoilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The show never returns to Katralla's world, and so we don't know what happens to the royal line after the Moya crew all leave.

However, we do see that later in the series:

> Crichton successfully fathers a child with Aeryn. This means that it isn't Katralla's genetic poisoning that makes him a compatible donor, and that human DNA is more broadly compatible with Peacekeeper DNA. It's not a guarantee that their child would also be able to have children, though. Many real life cross-breeds tend to be sterile.

In any event, as I understand from the story there was a time crunch where Katralla was required to have viable and direct heir or be replaced by her brother. However, once the heir had been fertilised, there was to be some considerable time where the parents are living statues before they become rulers and the child is actually born.

It's possible that the time crunch prevented Katralla being cured, but if the genetic poisoning were passed on it could still be treatable in the longer time available.

Comment: Though perhaps hypothetical (I don't recall any direct discussion of being able to restore Katralla's DNA), curing the DNA does seem a possibility consistent with the tech available to that world (they do seem to have mastered control over genes); and the time crunch does suitably explain why curing her DNA wouldn't have already occurred; I wrongly assumed the process irreversible, since it hadn't been done already. Also I hadn't considered it from the angle of the DNA poisoning being the thing that actually made Crichton compatible in the first place, so extra props for covering that as well!

Comment: It should also be noted in the comics (which are considered canon), Crichton and Aeryn's child exhibits some ability to manipulate time and matter, manifesting as sending Crichton to an unrealised reality, and saving Noranti from suffocating in space. I can't quite recall if it is said if this is from human/sebacean DNA mixing or something else.